# Showing the content of an array with printf (not echo)

Tags: bash, printf

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

$ a=("1st" "2nd")
$ echo "${a[*]}"
> 1st 2nd
$ echo "${a[@]}"
> 1st 2nd
$ printf "${a[*]}\n"
> 1st 2nd
$ printf "${a[@]}\n"
> 1st
```

Why does the last `printf` command fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should supply format to `printf command`:

```
printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}"
```

When you use `printf` like `printf "${a[@]}\n"` it is equivalent to:

```
printf "1st" "2nd\n"
```

And since there is no recognized format in 1st argument therefore only literal `1st` gets printed.

Comment: `printf "${a[@]}\n"` should expand to `printf "1st\n" "2nd\n"` and not `printf "1st" "2nd\n"`, no?

Comment: @1_CR: No at least on my `BASH 3.2.48` it appends `\n` to last element of the array only.